# How do I use Data Anotations to create a relationship between these tables?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, ef-database-first

My question is how do I create a relationship between two tables that have nonstandard column names using data anotations?

My business object is a "Rule". Each Rule has an optional "Client".

[image: db tables]

Diagram above shows PK and FK.

Here's what I tried - I didn't get any errors but I'm not seeing the Client properties in my app.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Partial Public Class Rule

    <Key>
    Public Property FWAClientHandling As Integer 'PK

    <ForeignKey("Client")>
    Public Property iClientID As Integer 'FK

    Public Property Client As Client 'Child object
End Class
```

Comment: That mainly depends on what you're querying.

Comment: Thanks @gert-arnold! What information can I add to this ticket to help you with the diagnosis?

Comment: @GertArnold Please understand I'm only asking how to create a relationship between two tables with data anotations. The answer I'm hoping for is just a few lines of code in the snippet above.

Comment: Yeah, but that looks OK. So now it depends on what the query looks like.

Comment: Query is generated automatically by DevExtreme. But I think you answered my question. It means the data anotations I supplied are not causing the problem. Do I need to have an array of Rules on the Client model?